# Django ImageField null=True doesn't make blank field equal to NULL

Tags: sql, django, database, sqlite, django-models

I have a model with this field:

```
carousel_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='news/%Y/%m/%d, null=True, blank=True)
```

I was wondering why exclude(carousel_image__isnull=True) and other queries that check if field is or isn't null aren't working.
I checked my sqlite3 db and received this:

```
sqlite> select carousel_image from asgeos_site_news;
news/2020/12/23/index.jpeg
news/2020/12/23/gradient-1.jpeg



( 3 blank lines )
```

I also tried adding WHERE carousel_image = NULL and it returned nothing.
Why my images are not null? They're just a blank lines. I have to use carousel_image__exact='' to exclude them right now.

Answer (score 1):

File fields can't be set to null in the db, [here's the reference from django documentation](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/10244)

```
blank = True
```

is enough.

blank is stored as ''

Comment: But it's 12 years old and modern documentation recommends to set null=True to file fields.

Comment: last modified 4 years ago. Would you mind share the link where it suggests?

Comment: ImageField or FileField is a string based fields which store the path of the file. Django suggests not to use null for any string based fields. Check out the latest doc: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#null

Comment: Oh thanks I must've misread it somewhere.